# Linking nodes algoritm for Visual Design

Tags: xna, c#, algorithm, path-finding, logic

I'm developing an editor for my game, and now it's time to make a visual scripting system to let designer modify behaviours.

[This video shows what i have done and the problem](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e9LEOp51v8M)

to resolve the link between nodes I'm using an A* path finding, 
when a path is set, I add a penalization bonus to each cell of the path, to avoid using the same cells for other path.

I would like that the lines do not intersect unnecesarily.

is there any algoritm or idea that allows me to do this better?

Comment: Interestingly, I just yesterday started working on a node-based user-oriented visual scripting system for AI behaviour. I've been looking into some of the open source circuit diagram software, to see how they do it.

Comment: You could also check out Blender's source, since it features a node-based materials editor, and a node-based logic editor.

Comment: The way you are doing it (A penalty in the node cost) is the way to do it with A*. You might also consider a penalty for any step that turns, which will clean up your messy corners. - in practice I think most things like this just draw a spline or something and intersections be damned.

Comment: @Blecki i think is a good idea the turn penalty, thanks

Comment: @Blecki, your idea did the trick... :) if you make the reply I will accept it as right answer

Comment: I have added the turn penalty, also I've applied a Pow(H, 1.3f) function to the heuristic function to penalize the farther nodes to  improve the number of cycles needed to find a solution. [Improved algoritm](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QfJzqmhP_VI)

Comment: Well I didn't actually answer your question. So.

Comment: @Blecki you have provided the idea to improve it... :)

Answer (score 1):

You could check out GraphViz for some inspiration: http://www.graphviz.org/Gallery.php

The tool itself produces static images, but it has a variety of modes for connecting nodes with limited overlap. Also it's open source in case you're interested in studying one of the algorithms that they use. Good luck.